# Test if all elements are in another list in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to test if `reference_list` contains all of the items in `required_strings`.

```
required_strings = ['apple','banana','carrot']

reference_list = [['apple','tree'],
                  ['banana','grass'],
                  ['carrot','grass']]
```

I want to get true or false as the test result. The expected answer is 'true'.

This is what I had attempted:

```
test = [i for i in reference_list if any(s in i for s in required_strings)]
print test
```

Comment: So if every item in main list is represented in one of the reference sublists, return True?

I'm not sure i understand the spec.

Comment: if any item in reference list is in required list ,then return True?

Comment: @pigletfly ALL the elements of 'required_strings' must be in any sublist of the 'reference_list'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by making use of `set` and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).  We're going to take advantage of some set theory and regard `required_strings` and `reference_list` as sets, and demonstrate that `required_strings <= reference_list`; that is, the required strings set is completely contained inside of the reference list.

First, use `itertools.chain` to flatten the shallow list.

```
from itertools import chain
chain(*reference_list) # Iterable object
```

Next, turn both the chained list and the tested list into sets and compare to see [if one set is completely contained](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) in the other.

```
from itertools import chain
set(required_strings) <= set(chain(*reference_list))
```

If you're keen on *not* using `chain`, then you can use [`sum(list_of_lists, [])`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22077964/1079354) to reduce it instead.

```
set(required_strings) <= set(sum(reference_lists, []))
```

However, I would strongly encourage that you use `set` instead of `list`, as this sort of problem is better suited towards a `set`. You also don't have to import it; you can just use the class much like you do `list`.

Comment: I want solve it just using lists and conditions stuffs without importing anythings.

Comment: @jose:  There's going to be code that you need to flatten a list, essentially; that's all `chain` is providing.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to try anything super fancy or concise until you have a working solution you understand.

Try at first to make your answer as similar to the english specification of the problem as you can. Basically you should loop over strings in the required list and check if they are in any of the sub lists. Here's a stub that can be made a function.

```
for req_string in required_strings:
   appears_in_reference = False
   for sub_list in reference_list:
       if req_string in sub_list:
           appears_in_reference = True
           break
   if not appears_in_reference:
       return False

return True
```

Answer (score 0):

*Python 2* This is one way to do it:

```
import itertools
required_strings = ['apple','banana','carrot']

reference_list = [['apple','tree'],
                  ['banana','grass'],
                  ['carrot','grass']]
x = list(itertools.chain(*reference_list))
print all(l in x for l in required_strings )
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comprehension that returns a list of bools:

```
>>> test = [(True if i in s else False) for i in required_strings for s in reference_list]
[True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

Alternatively, use a generator comprehension to check against the length of the original required strings list. Notice the use of ( ) instead of [ ].

```
>>> test = ((True if i in s else False) for i in required_strings for s in reference_list)
```

Then, check it against the length:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> for truthiness in test:
...     if truthiness == True:
...         counter += 1
>>> len(required_strings) == counter
True
```

Edit: this would probably only work in Python 3.4+ but I thought it would be worth putting forth.